# Show rendered node in jQuery modal through JSON

Tags: 8, modal-dialogs

Whenever a link has a specific class I want to show it as a jQuery modal. I have added the neccesarry data attributes to the link in order to be able to use it as a modal.

I have also created a route for nodes that has a custom controller that is run when a node is viewed with `?_format=json`. The controller returns the rendered node as JSON which seems to work fine.

To see the route definition look [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/284545/72672).

Here's my controller:

```
public function json(EntityInterface $node, $view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL) {
  $build = $this->entityTypeManager->getViewBuilder('node')->view($node, $view_mode);
  $output = $this->renderer->renderRoot($build);

  return new JsonResponse($output);
}
```

And here's the JS that makes the link a modal:

```
if ($(context).find('.class').length > 0) {
  $(context).find('.class').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('data-dialog-type', 'modal').addClass('use-ajax');
  });
}
```

The only problem is that when clicking the link it gives an error saying:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Why does `JSON.parse` fail to parse the JSON data that `JsonResponse` generates?

Comment: `JsonResponse` is a Symfony class, not Drupal. And yes, it sends valid JSON. What has your own debugging led you to understand? Is it valid JSON or not?

Comment: I have tried to use JSON.parse() on the JSON data that I receive from my controller, it gives the error, JSON.parse: unexpected ...

Comment: Have you run it through an external linter? Tried it in different browsers? Tried returning a known good static JSON that works in other instances? We can't see inside your environment here so you're going to need to do the bulk of the debugging

Comment: Yes I tried that too, it was also failing.

Comment: Ok I will try to do some more debugging, thanks.

Comment: I guess it's possible you've found a bug in Symfony's `JsonResponse`, or in Drupal's renderer, in that case, but it feels like either would be unlikely. Try setting the headers and dumping manually with `json_encode` to see if you get the same response

Comment: You probably need to pass an array to the JSON constructor, and `renderRoot()` returns an HTML string.

Comment: Check the docs - pass an array to the constructor not a flat string: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response - and like Clive said we need more debug info.

Comment: Thank you, I will debug further and then give an update when I have further information :)

Comment: Hi @all I found out that I needed to attach the `core/drupal.dialog.ajax` library, adding that together with the answer below solved the problem. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you to check with `AjaxResponse`, it will return the json response object.

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();
```

And use below to open content in modal or as dialog.

```
$response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($title, $content, ['width' => '700'])); // To open a modal window
```

OR

```
$response->addCommand(new OpenDialogCommand('#some-element', $title, $content, ['width' => '700'])); // to open a dialog window
```

`$title` refers to title of your node and `$content` refers to content that you want to show in the modal. It is also possible to define some properties like width in it.

And in the end just return it's response like below:

```
return $response;
```

Remember to include `AjaxResponse` in it your controller file.

```
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
```

I hope the above will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. This actually seems to work perfectly. I forgot to include the `core/drupal.dialog.ajax` library, after including that it all worked. Don't really see why this answer deserves a downvote :)

Comment: That's really good. My main concern was that your problem should be solved and it would make me happy if my little knowledge can help you out.